# Add --all option to wscript

Tags: waf

I have several targets defined in my top `wscript`, let's call them `build_a`, `build_b` and `build_c`.

How do I add a function `all` to my `wscript`, that builds all these targets (doesn't matter if sequential or in parallel).

So in dummy python code, I expect something like this:

```py
def all():
    tar = ['configure', 'build_a', 'build_b', 'build_c']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple to compose commands:

```py
from waflib import Options

def all(bld):
    commands_after = Options.commands
    Options.commands = ['configure', 'build_a', 'build_b', 'build_c']
    Options.commands += commands_after
```

See https://waf.io/book/#_custom_commands (§7.1.2 Command composition)

waf consume Options.commands while processing it. So you can use:

```sh
waf all test

# equivalent to waf configure build_a build_b build_c test
```